# If you hire a tax attorney to do your OVDP paperwork, are the fees tax deductible?

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-deduction, fbar

I know that tax preparation fees are tax deductible in US federal taxes, but I'm not sure if the failure of FBAR and reporting international passive interest income (followed by a subsequent willingness to correct those mistakes) qualifies you to make the same deductions. If the answer is yes, do I have to forgo the standard deduction? Is there a limit to how much I can deduct? Where do I enter the deduction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FBAR is enforced by the IRS, and OVDP is administered by the IRS, and as part of the program your tax returns will be examined. So I'd *personally* say that the answer is yes - treat it as part of the tax preparation fees.

If you want to deduct tax preparation fees, you can do it as part of your *itemized* deductions, subject to the 2% AGI threshold, so yes - you have to itemize.

It is entered on [Schedule A, line 22](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040sa.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a quick follow-up, if you don't mind. If my credit card got charged for 5k in Dec 2013 (for the tax attorney fee), but I paid the bill for this credit card in Jan 2014 can I deduct for 2014 rather than 2013? The reason I'm asking is because the standard deduction is a little higher than 5k and I'll spend more money on the attorney in 2014.

Comment: Technically you can deduct when you paid, which is 2013. Credit card bill is not deductible.